# android: make zip file of folder existing in Sdcard ,contains lots of .vcf file

Tags: android

i want to make a zipped of a folder which is in side the the sdcard of device i want to make a zipped file of its and want to send as attachment as in mail. 
so pls any one suggest me how to make a zipped file and when my zipping is  in progress, display the percentage of task finished , means as asynchronously .  means visible to the user as zipping is is progress ..
pls help me 
waiting for response.

```
public void get()
            {
                vfile = "Contacts" + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".vcf";

                //String vfile = "Contacts"+".vcf";
                //cursor.moveToFirst();

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

For creating **.zip archive**..

Android has a in-built class [`ZipOutputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) support of **java.util.zip** package.

This class provides an implementation of `FilterOutputStream` that compresses data entries into a ZIP-archive output stream.

`ZipOutputStream` is used to write `ZipEntries` to the underlying stream. Output from `ZipOutputStream` conforms to the `ZipFile` file format.

Also look at this article this may be help you..

[Zipping Files with Android (Programmatically)](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)

For displaying progress bar when you are crating a .zip archive you can use [Android-AsynTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). start your progress dialog on `onPreExecute()` of `AsyncTask` and stop or dismiss it on `onPostExecute()` also your .zip archive creating code put in `doInBAckground()` of `AsyncTask`.